# How enable/disable item depend on counter in JSON?

Tags: json, vue.js

I have got next JSON:

```
"questions": 
{
    "id": 1, "question": "Select one color", "answers": [
                {"id": 1, "answer" : "Green", "isSelected" : false}, 
                {"id": 2, "answer": "Red", "isSelected" : false}, 
                {"id": 3, "answer": "Blue", "isSelected" : false],
                {"id": 4, "answer": "Black", "isSelected" : false],
    "MaxAllowedChoice" : 2,
}
```

And I am display in with next code:

```
 <div v-for="question in questions">
    <div v-for="firstLevelAnswer in questions.answers">                
      <span class="firstLevelAnswer"><input type="checkbox" class="big-checkbox" v-model="firstLevelAnswer.isSelected"/>{{firstLevelAnswer.answer}}</span>
      <span v-if="firstLevelAnswer.isTextInput"><input type="text"/></span>
           |  firstLevelAnswer.isSelected: {{firstLevelAnswer.isSelected}}
</div>
```

It's my not work directry, because all of it are striped from big project. But in mostry it ok.

I need to way to disable checkboxs when `MaxAllowedChoice` count are reach n. For example if user clicked on Green and Red he can't click on any other item.

What is the best way to do it with Vue?

Comment: you want to enable/disabled something, not show/hide. you should fix the title of your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/d1rxbe0o/

You could use the [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out all the selected answers of a specific question and compare the length of result with the `MaxAllowedChoice`.

Then, you should bind the comparison result to the `disabled` property.

Hope this helps.